# Openshift rest api using java and object creation

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise, openshift-online

Is there any way to take a yaml file and create object out of it like template , quota and others using java

Comment: Are you looking for java equivalent of `oc create -f`?

Comment: Yes. I am looking for the java equivalent of oc create -f